# Bootstrap 3 carousel caption zooming up through navbar

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

im trying to design a website with a navbar at the top and a carousel immediately following it. The caption for this carousel is a jumbotron. However, everytime i zoom in or change the page size the carousel remains fine but the caption zooms in way too much and moves to the top of the page through the navbar. Is there a way to maintain the position and size of the text relative to the carousel?

Thanks, help would be much appreciated.

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" style="height: 100%; width=100%; display:block; padding-top: 80px">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to = "0" class = "active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to = "1" class = "active"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner ">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="img/city8.jpg" alt = "Main" class = "img-responsive " style="width:100%; height:100%; display:block;"> 
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <div class="jumbotron myBackground" id="caption1">
          <h1 class="whitney" id="bigName></h1>
          <h3 class="gotham" id="university"></h3>
          <p id = "software"></p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button" id="learn">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: First you would have to make sure your carousel is the context of the content.  Then make the percentages and ems (relative values) for the target size. The formula is `target ÷ context = result`.

Comment: Yes but the thing is the text moves all the way up and zooms in appropriately but its being blocked by the navbar such that you cannot see it anymore.